# Not able to validate the correct username and password in symfony

Tags: symfony4

I have used following lines of code to create a user.

```
$newUser = new User();
$plainPassword = 'test';
$hashPassword = $this->passwordEncoder->encodePassword($newUser, $plainPassword);

$newUser->setUserName($filterArray['username']);
$newUser->setPassword($hashPassword);
$newUser->setCreatedDatetime();
$newUser->setStatus('active');

$this->entityManager->persist($newUser);
$this->entityManager->flush();
```

Now when I try to login

```
$this->passwordEncoder->isPasswordValid($user, $credentials->getPassword())
```

This line is always returning `false`. Here `$user` outputs

```
App\Entity\User {#592
  -id: 1
  -loginName: "test"
  -loginPassword: "$2y$13$S5nEPTFznoemyO1.WsBxl.beyGL4i1YuwteDx7GDtzP"
  -createdDatetime: DateTime @1602489653 {#596
    date: 2020-10-12 10:00:53.0 Europe/Berlin (+02:00)
  }
  -status: "active"
}
```

Can anybody help me on this.

Comment: What's `passwordEncoder`? An instance of `PasswordEncoder` or `UserPasswordEncoder`? And `credentials` contains the plain password?

Comment: Its `UserPasswordEncoder`

Comment: Everything seems right code-wise, provided the credentials match. Does your user return a `salt` or do you have a specific algorithm set in your config?